# see "creation date" and "last update" in Jupyter notebook

Tags: date, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I wonder if there is a way to add a column "creation date" and "updated date" in Jupyter Notebook file browsing scree (i.e. "Home" - http://localhost:8888/tree).

Comment: I'd really like to do this as well but have so far not found a way.

Comment: @lara if you're still interested try my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

They are working on the feature:

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/943

It will be available in version 5.0

Comment: it looks like only "last modified" was added but not "created at"

Comment: Did you check jupyterlab?

Comment: yeah, that's actually the tool im currently using and want the "created_at" column for. it looks like the same as `notebook` and doesn't have that one.